# How to retrieve struct pointer from Go list

Tags: go, pointers, linked-list

I have a struct

```
type clientData struct {
    msg    Message
    connId int
}
```

I'm trying to add this to a Go [List](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list) as such

```
l := list.New()
l.PushBack(&clientData {
    msg: Message {
       some fields  
    },
    connId: 1
});
```

Now, how do I get back the data as a `*clientData` data type back from the List ? I tried `l.Front().Value` but that returns an interface... I'm pretty sure I don't understand the marshalling/marshalling logic for Go here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection in `go` contains a `raw` [types](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#Element) (`Element.Value`  empty `interface{}`). You have to assign the type every time, when get value from the `list`:

```
l := list.New()
l.PushBack(&clientData {
    msg: Message {
       some fields  
    },
    connId: 1,
})

cd, ok := l.Front().Value.(*clientData)
if !ok {
    panic(errors.New("not a client type"))
}
fmt.Println(cd.connId)
```